# How can I make the scrollbar go beyond parent's padding and maximum width?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

`<section className="max-w-[1600px] m-auto w-full h-[100dvh] py-5 px-5">`

I have this parent section. It has a padding of 20 pixels on the x-axis and a maximum width of 1600 pixels.

`<div className="flex flex-nowrap overflow-auto gap-9 flex-1">`

Then I have this child div. It has a flexbox display to arrange the elements horizontally.

```
    <section className="max-w-[1600px] m-auto w-full h-[100dvh] py-5 px-5">
            <div className="flex flex-nowrap overflow-auto gap-9 flex-1"> <--The horizontal scroll wrapper
                <div className="w-[300px] bg-red-50" style={{ flex: "0 0 auto" }}></div>
                <div className="w-[300px] bg-red-50" style={{ flex: "0 0 auto" }}></div>
                <div className="w-[300px] bg-red-50" style={{ flex: "0 0 auto" }}></div>
                <div className="w-[300px] bg-red-50" style={{ flex: "0 0 auto" }}></div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

This is the entire HTML structure. I want the "The horizontal scroll wrapper" to bypass the right-side padding and the maximum width set by the parent (1600px).

[image]

I attached the above image to show what I'm looking for. The right side bypassed the padding and the maximum width set.

```html
<section class="max-w-[1600px] m-auto w-full h-[100dvh] py-5 px-5">
  <div class="flex flex-nowrap overflow-auto gap-9 h-full">

    <div class="w-[3000px] bg-red-50" style="flex: 0 0 auto;"></div>
    <div class="w-[3000px] bg-red-50" style="flex: 0 0 auto;"></div>
    <div class="w-[3000px] bg-red-50" style="flex: 0 0 auto;"></div>
    <div class="w-[3000px] bg-red-50" style="flex: 0 0 auto;"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

The snippet (increased width for PC users) above showcases padding on the x-axis and a maximum width of 1600px applied. I want the horizontal scroll's right side to reach the screen's end, bypassing the padding and maximum width styles applied to its parent.

Comment: I took a crack at putting your markup into a demo snippet. Please revise as necessary to show the problem.

Comment: Set **maxWidth** and **padding** to the wrapping container of inner elements, & not on the `<section>` itself. Here's is [result](https://play.tailwindcss.com/FkBIW6vr0l), if this is what you want to achieve.